# Active Admin member action

Tags: activeadmin

I have two models :

**Project**

```
has_one :abstract
```

**Abstract**

```
belongs_to :project
```

After reading the active admin documentation I do this :

```
member_action :abstracts do
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @abstract = @project.abstract
end
```

Then I create an abstracts.html.arb in admin/project and I can access to it by this url 
/admin/projects/:id/abstracts

My question is how can I add the form to create/edit/delete/show abstract from here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax to render forms ([Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7908344/1102013)):

```
render active_admin_template('edit.html.arb'), :layout => false
```

But according code you provided - you should use belongs_to syntax from inherited resources.

> Belongs to
>
> Finally, our Projects are going to get some Tasks. Then you create a
>   TasksController and do:
>
> ```
> class TasksController < InheritedResources::Base
>   belongs_to :project
> end
> ```
>
> belongs_to accepts several options to be able to configure the
>   association. For example, if you want urls like
>   /projects/:project_title/tasks, you can customize how
>   InheritedResources find your projects:
>
> ```
> class TasksController < InheritedResources::Base
>   belongs_to :project, :finder => :find_by_title!, :param => :project_title
> end
> ```

Active Admin is based on it, so it should work. [Documentation](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources).